# How do I merge a point attribute table to a polygon attribute table in QGIS or GRASS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, grass-gis, point, attribute-table

I have a point layer containing the following data:

[image]

I want the following polygon areas to be added to the point attribute table as all the points occur inside the various features of the polygon layer:

[image]

There are thousands of points but under 50 features in the polygon layer:

[image: Polygon layer overlaid on point layer - I want both to be one, i.e. each point must have the section's segment code ascribed to it]

PLEASE NOTE that I have attempted the following plugins/algorithms:

- Merge
- Join attributes by Location
- Join attributes Table
- spatialJoin (that uses refFunctions)

Please help!

Comment: What happened when you used `Join attributes by Location`? Also, the **MMQGIS** plugin contains a `Spatial Join` tool which you could try.

Comment: @Joseph the Join attr. by Location delivers NULL cells and remember it asks for algebraic metrics to be computed so categorical data aren't just copied over. I will attempt **MMQGIS**...

Comment: @Joseph, **MMQGIS** worked. Thanks but, pity only a single tool works for this type of join.